# Proper way to use where clause while including TempData? ASP NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am doing a project and I am trying to display Reviews based on `StaffID` stored by `TempData`. I used a where clause to display the specific reviews based on the user's `StaffID` that is stored by `TempData`.

What I am trying to achieve is here : [image]

In this picture above, I **hard coded** it and I believe my `Where` clause works properly. I just need to know how to properly use `Where` clause while including the `TempData` inside so it takes the `StaffID` directly from the `SQL` Database.

**This picture below is what happens when I run my code without using hard coded values from my DataBase, thus it is not working**. If someone knows, please do help me. Thank you so much

[image]

`Controller code(where RevieweeID.Equals(@TempData["StaffID"]` is the part where I need help with):

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    var applicationUserClass = _context.Review.Where(r => r.ReviewCategoryID.ToString().Equals("601C21CF-0916-4C40-B158-D7253858386F")).Where(r => r.RevieweeID.Equals(@TempData["StaffID"])).Include(r => r.ReviewCategorys).Include(r => r.Staff).Include(r => r.Staffs);
    return View(await applicationUserClass.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: @TempData to me looks like you are trying to use Razor syntax insed c# code.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using Razor Pages.

Comment: That aside you canot use razor templating inside a c# method.

Comment: Oh. Any ideas how do I display the where clause then by still using tempdata.

Comment: The problem with your code as i can see it is that you use the razor syntax in it. Wether you tempdata object is initialized i do not know but in bgeneral it is not a good way to pass data.

Comment: The `TempData` directly [exists as a property on the ViewComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewcomponent.tempdata?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use TempData with where,you can use TempData["xxx"].ToString():

Here is a demo worked:

```
Student s = _context.Student.Where(stu => stu.Id.ToString().Equals(TempData["id"].ToString())).ToList()[0];
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Omg.. I have been cracking my head over this thing, Im just a student so I am quite inexperienced but I added in the last part TempData["xxx"].ToString(); and it worked for me.